# Rapid ajax requests to servlet causing performance issues

Tags: servlets

I'm new to programming with servlets and ajax. I have client side code that I use to track mouse actions over an image. I need to send the coordinates during a drag to the servlet for processing. I use ajax for this. I have the code working but there seems to be a lag in processing the requests in the servlet. Specifically with dragging.

**Client Side Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


    // detect mousedown
   $("#imgslot").mousedown(function(event){

      var leftClick = false;       // if user clicked the left mouse button                                                     
      var rightClick = false;      // if user clicked the right mouse button
      var interaction={type:"",action:"",lClick:"",rClick:"",x:"null",y:""};

      //if the client left clicks
      if(event.which===1){

          leftClick=true;
      }

              //if the client left clicks
      if(event.which===3){

          rightClick=true;
      }

      interaction={type:"interaction",action:"mousedown",lClick:leftClick,rClick:rightClick,x:event.clientX,y:event.clientY};
      sendAjax(interaction);

      // detect dragging
      $(this).on('mousemove',function(event){

              interaction={type:"interaction",action:"drag",lClick:leftClick,rClick:rightClick,x:event.clientX,y:event.clientY};
              sendAjax(interaction);

        // detect mouseup
        }).mouseup(function(event){

            interaction={type:"interaction",action:"mouseup",lClick:leftClick,rclick:rightClick,x:event.clientX,y:event.clientY};
            sendAjax(interaction);

            rightClick =  false;
            leftClick = false;

            $(this).off('mousemove');
            $(this).off('mouseup');

            });       

         });
});

function sendAjax(message)
{
           $.ajax({
           url: "myServlet",
           type: "POST",
           data: message,

           success: function (data) {

            }
           }); 
 }
```

**In Servlet:** Simply printing the requests to test the performance

```
if (request.getParameter("type") != null) {
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("action"));
         if (request.getParameter("type").equals("interaction")) {
             sendMouseActions(request.getParameter("action"), request.getParameter("lClick"), request.getParameter("rClick"), request.getParameter("x"), request.getParameter("y"));
         }
}
```

My biggest issue is that on a drag, because I have to send each coordinate, when I view my output, it continues to print out that I'm dragging even after I stopped the drag operation. This lag continues for sometime. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Of course that will have bad performance. You should handle mouse movement stuff in javascript on the client side. For drag and drop send servlet only begin and final end position. Ajax requests are asynchronous, so you'll end up getting the coordinates out of order anyway if you you send a request each time onmousemove is fired.  That's probably why its telling you that you are still dragging after you stopped; requests are getting out of order.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Per the requirements though, I need to track mousemovement using client side scripting and then send all of it to the servlet. For instance I cannot just send beginning and ending coordinates for drags. I have to send everything in between to. Maybe ajax is not the solution I should be looking at?

Comment: You could save all the points in array in javascript and send at the end. Are you making a drawing app? Even if you aren't, looking at some HTML5 drawing apps that send the image to the server at the end might help.